# Conditional statement to check if user exists in JSON file (or mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, indexing, mongoose

**Background**

The JSON file is being generated from a mongoDB with mongoose ODM. However it difficult for me to add a mongoose query to the if statement as I get alot of errors.

**The JSON Approach**

*Using this approach, I cache the mongoDB collection to a JSON file, the attempt to read off the ids.*

I have a mods.json file which looks like this (Array Of Objects):

```
[
  {
    "userid": "58258161"
  },
  {
    "userid": "135207785"
  },
  {
    "userid": "268339963"
  },
  {
    "userid": "210152609"
  }
]
```

The JSON file above contains a list of users who are allowed to execute a certain Telegram Bot command.

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var mods = require('./mods.json');

bot.onText(/\/test/i, function (msg) {
    var fromId = msg.from.id;
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    for (index in mods) {
        if (fromId == config.owner || mods[index].userid) {
            console.log('You Are A Mod!');
    } else {
        console.log('Not A Mod');
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'You are not a mod');
    }
    } 
});
```

**A brief explanation of how the above is supposed to work:**

When the bot receives a "/test" command it is supposed to check if the message is from the owner whose id is stored in the config.json file or any moderator whose unique id is stored in the mods.json file.

**The problem**

The following code checks through every single id to confirm whether the message is from a mod. And subsequently spits out multiple messages of 'You are not a mod'. Which would be the best method to confirm the user is a mod in the conditional statement 'if'.

**The Mongo Approach**

When querying with moongose a callback is required, I dont know exactly how to create a if conditional in such a scenario. However this method would obviously be better in such a situation.

Comment: You should try to get a mongoDB query working if you can since that is what it's built for. You can post those errors and we can help.

Comment: check the edit above

Comment: made a custom mongoose method can attempt to find that

Comment: What I suggest is that rather than having an array of objects, you just have an object instead. Here's what it'll look like:

    mods = {
        "58258161": {
            //extra data here
        },
        "135207785": {},
        "268339963": {},
        "210152609": {}
    };

This way, if you need to check if any user is a moderator, you can get `Object.keys(mods)`, which returns an array of keys (in this case, moderator IDs) and you can simply check if the ID lies in this array.

NOTE: Sorry, for bad formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.some` instead, to check if the ID is in the array, that way the message won't be outputted on every iteration, only when it's done checking

```
var isMod = fromId == config.owner || mods.some(x => fromId == x.userid);

if ( isMod ) {
    console.log('You Are A Mod!');
} else {
    console.log('Not A Mod');
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'You are not a mod');
}
```

Preferably you'd construct a query to ask the database instead, something like

```
model.find({'mods.userid': config.owner}, function (err, docs) {...
```

Comment: Or rather `fromId == config.owner || mods.some(x => x.userid);`

Comment: @str - yupp, that makes a lot more sense, not checking the same variables in every iteration.